# %dopar% for long time series segmentation (breakpoints)

Tags: r, time-series, regression, segments

I have a long time series. In the following example only the first 100 lines are enclosed.
After running the lines:

```
Lines <- "Hour,PF
1,26/11/2014 13:00, 0 
2,26/11/2014 14:00,0.070
3,26/11/2014 15:00,0.070
4,26/11/2014 16:00,0.050
5,26/11/2014 17:00,0.060
6,26/11/2014 18:00,0.020
7,26/11/2014 19:00,0.040
8,26/11/2014 20:00,0.020
9,26/11/2014 21:00,0.020
10,26/11/2014 22:00,0.010
11,26/11/2014 23:00,0.020
12,27/11/2014 0:00,0.010
13,27/11/2014 1:00,0.010
14,27/11/2014 2:00,0.020
15,27/11/2014 3:00,0.010
16,27/11/2014 4:00,0.020
17,27/11/2014 5:00,0.010
18,27/11/2014 6:00,0.020
19,27/11/2014 7:00,0.010
20,27/11/2014 8:00,0.010
21,27/11/2014 9:00,0.060
22,27/11/2014 10:00,0.060
23,27/11/2014 11:00,0.060
24,27/11/2014 12:00,0.060
25,27/11/2014 13:00,0.080
26,27/11/2014 14:00,0.060
27,27/11/2014 15:00,0.060
28,27/11/2014 16:00,0.040
29,27/11/2014 17:00,0.060
30,27/11/2014 18:00,0.060
31,27/11/2014 19:00,0.020
32,27/11/2014 20:00,0.010
33,27/11/2014 21:00,0.020
34,27/11/2014 22:00,0.010
35,27/11/2014 23:00,0.010
36,28/11/2014 0:00,0.020
37,28/11/2014 1:00,0.010
38,28/11/2014 2:00,0.020
39,28/11/2014 3:00,0.010
40,28/11/2014 4:00,0.010
41,28/11/2014 5:00,0.020
42,28/11/2014 6:00,0.010
43,28/11/2014 7:00,0.020
44,28/11/2014 8:00,0.010
45,28/11/2014 9:00,0.010
46,28/11/2014 10:00,0.020
47,28/11/2014 11:00,0.010
48,28/11/2014 12:00,0.040
49,28/11/2014 13:00,0.060
50,28/11/2014 14:00,0.010
51,28/11/2014 15:00,0.010
52,28/11/2014 16:00,0.020
53,28/11/2014 17:00,0.010
54,28/11/2014 18:00,0.020
55,28/11/2014 19:00,0.010
56,28/11/2014 20:00,0.010
57,28/11/2014 21:00,0.020
58,28/11/2014 22:00,0.010
59,28/11/2014 23:00,0.020
60,29/11/2014 0:00,0.010
61,29/11/2014 1:00,0.010
62,29/11/2014 2:00,0.020
63,29/11/2014 3:00,0.010
64,29/11/2014 4:00,0.010
65,29/11/2014 5:00,0.020
66,29/11/2014 6:00,0.010
67,29/11/2014 7:00,0.020
68,29/11/2014 8:00,0.010
69,29/11/2014 9:00,0.010
70,29/11/2014 10:00,0.020
71,29/11/2014 11:00,0.010
72,29/11/2014 12:00,0.020
73,29/11/2014 13:00,0.010
74,29/11/2014 14:00,0.010
75,29/11/2014 15:00,0.020
76,29/11/2014 16:00,0.010
77,29/11/2014 17:00,0.020
78,29/11/2014 18:00,0.010
79,29/11/2014 19:00,0.010
80,29/11/2014 20:00,0.020
81,29/11/2014 21:00,0.010
82,29/11/2014 22:00,0.020
83,29/11/2014 23:00,0.010
84,30/11/2014 0:00,0.010
85,30/11/2014 1:00,0.020
86,30/11/2014 2:00,0.010
87,30/11/2014 3:00,0.020
88,30/11/2014 4:00,0.010
89,30/11/2014 5:00,0.010
90,30/11/2014 6:00,0.020
91,30/11/2014 7:00,0.010
92,30/11/2014 8:00,0.020
93,30/11/2014 9:00,0.020
94,30/11/2014 10:00,0.070
95,30/11/2014 11:00,0.060
96,30/11/2014 12:00,0.050
97,30/11/2014 13:00,0.060
98,30/11/2014 14:00,0.040
99,30/11/2014 15:00,0.050
100,30/11/2014 16:00,0.070"
```

I run the following:

```
library (zoo)
library (strucchange)

z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, tz = "", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", sep = ",")
bp <- breakpoints(z ~ 1, h = 2)
```

The last command of `breakpoints` is stuck for long time series. Is there a way to solve it maybe with `%dopar%` ?

Comment: When I use about 1000 observation it takes very long (I think about more than 30 minutes I don't remember the exact duration) with Intel i7. When it goes to 2000 and over it took more than 15 hours and there were no results.

Comment: What do you mean by "stuck"? At what time-series length does `breakpoints()` get "stuck"? Knowing this would be important in comparing the parallelized and non-parallelized performance of `breakpoints()`. Otherwise see answer for a `hpc` implementation of `breakpoints()`, see if it unsticks things ;-)..cheers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#Load necessary libs
library('foreach')
library('doParallel')

#Register parallel backend
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
registerDoParallel(cl, cores = detectCores() - 1)

#Run breakpoints(), note  usage of the `hpc` argument, see `?breakpoints`
bp <- breakpoints(z ~ 1, h=2, hpc='foreach')

#Deregister parallel backend
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Shekeine. It works! However it seem that the time for 1000 observation is similar with the hpc and without it. I'll try to run for 2500 the whole night and see if there are results at the morning.

Comment: Is there a way to accelerate the processing by using Redis for example?

Comment: No idea, but I think what`s really needed here to speed things up is bigger processing power i.e. a better, bigger, fancier computer. If that cannot be found then another option might be to down-sample your time series to a lower frequency (hence a shorter ts)...Perhaps find a way to estimate the trade-off between the down-sampling magnitude and associated signal loss and pick the "optimal" frequency to down-sample to...mmhhhh..If I may ask, what kind of data are you working with? Perhaps you could work with a lower frequency...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I need to use the h=2. Is there a way to know i advance the optimal frequency for usage? Maybe something that will anticipate the BIC?

Comment: was just a suggestion off the top of my head...try googling around and if you find something, post it back here: would be interested, can help with the code. cheers..